# Передаем параметры с Python в Bash

Tags: python, bash

Нужно написать небольшой обход строки на `Python`.

Всего имеем 4 аргумента: `arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, arg_4`. Они всегда одинаковы и имеют формат `string`.
Передается строка вида: `['arg1', 'arg2', ...]`
Аргументов может быть всегда разное количество — от 1 до 4, не больше, но сами аргументы всегда одинаковы и не меняют значений.

Нужно передать все эти аргументы в `Bash` скрипт.

Comment: Что значит имеют формат `string`? Куда строка передается? Передать аргументы как, вызвать какой-то скрипт с этими аргументами?

Comment: да, вызвать какой-то скрипт допустим таким образом:
`/tmp/script.sh arg1 arg2`

Comment: *"Аргументов может быть всегда разное количество"* -- откуда аргументы в Питон программе появляются?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно проверить, есть ли в заданной строке указанные аргументы, и, если есть, вызвать из баша с ними скрипт. Если предположить, что строка, подающаяся на вход всегда корректная, то тогда можно сделать так:

```
import os, re

string = "['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4']" # строка с аргументами
script = "/tmp/script.sh" # путь к вашему скрипту

os.system("{0} {1}".format(script, ' '.join(map(str, re.findall(r"\w+", string)))))
# вызовет команду /tmp/script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 в шелле и перенаправит
# весь вывод в интерпретатор
```